# Getting identical values from two arrays with different structures and indexes in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I've got two arrays with the following structures (one array has more lines than the other one):

**first_array**

```
['1', 'ASUS N56', '1', 'K0AK2M1A', '223422', '0828384']
['2', 'LG Flatron', '1', 'N10S021', '091923', '293821']
['3', 'Philips LCD', '1', 'Y82K91N', '892812', '909128']
```

**second_array**

```
['3265 Olive Street', 'ASUS N56', 'K0AK2M1A', 'no']
['5000 Orange Street', 'Philips LCD', 'Y82K91N', 'yes']
['6000 Banana Street', 'Samsung LCD', 'ABWS092', 'no']
```

I can access both of them with the subindexes, like this:

```
print(first_array[3])
```

Out: K0AK2M1A
I need to cycle through both of the arrays and compare values first_array[i][3] and second_array[i][2]. As a beginner programmer my first thought was to loop them through with a for loop, but I had no idea, what I should pick as range, but this is pretty much what I want.

```
for i in range(...):
    if first_array[i][3] == second_array[i][2]:
        duplicate_values.append(first_array[i][3])
```

And this would probably only compare the values on the same line (e.g. `[0][2]` and `[0][3]`. but not `[0][2]` and `[1][3]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the lists and comparing them sublist to sublist misses the fact that they may be in different orders. Instead I would make a `set` and intersect them

```
>>> set(i[3] for i in first).intersection(i[2] for i in second)
{'Y82K91N', 'K0AK2M1A'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use itertools.product to compare each element in first against every element in second:

```
first = [
    ['1', 'ASUS N56', '1', 'K0AK2M1A', '223422', '0828384'],
    ['2', 'LG Flatron', '1', 'N10S021', '091923', '293821'],
    ['3', 'Philips LCD', '1', 'Y82K91N', '892812', '909128'],
    ]

second = [
    ['3265 Olive Street', 'ASUS N56', 'K0AK2M1A', 'no'],
    ['5000 Orange Street', 'Philips LCD', 'Y82K91N', 'yes'],
    ['6000 Banana Street', 'Samsung LCD', 'ABWS092', 'no'],
    ]

from itertools import product

for f,s in product(first, second):
    if f[3] == s[2]:
        print f[3]
```

Prints

```
K0AK2M1A
Y82K91N
```